# Styling difference in Chrome incognito tab

Tags: html, css

## [mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N1UO.jpg)

Styling a file upload button to 'display:none' is ignored in a normal Chrome tab on mobile device, but works in a incognito tab. Can't work out why.

Have tried on Firefox app on mobile and displays correctly

Comment: Is your style sheet cached? try ctrl f5

Comment: @Pete problem is on a mobile device not on a PC, have restarted the Chrome app on the mobile, which I assume will refresh the cache?

Comment: @Pete restarting phone twice cleaned the cache, all working fine now thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.